# Two different PPPoE accounts, one ADSL line, same ISP?

Tags: home-networking, ad-hoc-network, wired-networking, networkmanager

My friend and I have the same ISP with 2Mbps uplink.

I added my PPPoE profile along with my friend's in his ADSL modem gateway and both PPPoE profiles are assigned different WAN IP addresses.

Now what I want is :

Whichever device I connect to his ADSL line should connect to the internet via my PPPoE and keep his PPPoE free for him.

Is it possible?

If yes, then when we are using our personal accounts, on same ADSL modem and same ISP (line) — will we both get 2Mbps speeds simultaneously on our respective devices?

Comment: Unlikely, the line speed depends on the ADSL profile, not how many devices are connected.

Comment: @DavidPostill Adsl profile means the PPPOE accounts?

Comment: No. It is the line profile. "The exchange sets an initial IP profile for your line as soon as it detects an active broadband service. It then monitors the line's speed for several days and adjusts the IP profile to a rate slightly less than the regular maximum speed that the line is able to handle. Generally speaking, this maximum possible speed is usually related to the length of the line between your home and the telephone exchange. The shorter the distance, the faster the speed your line can support."

Comment: In addition the ISP will configure the DSLAM in the exchange (where your line terminates) with the maximum speed as per your contract with the ISP.

Comment: @DavidPostill Okay getting the point. So at one moment only 1 of 2 PPPOE are working?

Comment: In addition the ADSL line will only work with one ADSL Modem attached (his) so your PPoE settings are irrelevant. I'm surprised the connection even works with 2 lots of PPoE settings ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes and both shows UPLINK and Different WAN IP. But I m not able to tell through which the net is working though speed remains the same as you said.